# Remove iPad anchor outline

Tags: css, ipad, anchor, outline

Really, that simple. I have anchors set without outline, a la: `a {outline:none}`

Is there something else? Check out the screenshot below

http://cl.ly/0s1C2g1V0v0W2C351M1P

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an outline but a specific iPad (and iPhone?) rule : http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-tap-highlight-color